# Problem with overriding a method (using generic types)

Tags: c++, generics, inheritance, overriding

I keep getting this error when trying to override the "Solver::solve(P key)" function:
[image]

> Non-virtual member function marked 'override' hides virtual member function.
>   hidden overloaded virtual function 'Solver<, std::vector>,std::allocator>>>>::solve' declared here: type mimsatch...

Solver.h:

```
...
template<class P, class S>
class Solver{
 public:
  virtual S solve(P key) = 0;
};
```

B.h

```
using namespace std;

namespace server_side {
class B: public Solver<string, vector<vector<double>>> {
 public:
  string solve(vector<vector<double>> mat) override {//<--- The error is here, on "override"
    code...
  }
```

However, if I replace the `vector<vector<double>>>` to `std::string`, it works perfectly. 
The problem is that I need it to be `vector<vector<double>>>`...

Alternative code that works:

```
...
using namespace std;

namespace server_side {
class B: public Solver<string, string> {
 public:
  string solve(string mat) override {
    code...
  }
```

Any ideas how to solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inherit from `Solver<string, vector<vector<double>>>`. `P` is `string`, `S` is `vector<vector<double>>`, and the pure virtual function has the following signature

```
virtual vector<vector<double>> solve(string) = 0;
```

You're trying to override it with

```
string solve(vector<vector<double>>);
```

You need to swap something.

`Solver<string, string>` works, because `P` and `S` are the same, so the order doesn't matter.

---

Also note that taking `vector<vector<double>> mat` by value is very inefficient for large matrices. Unless you really need a copy, you might want to take it by `const vector<vector<double>>&` instead.